# Get the neighboring vertices and incident edges from a vertex in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I need to get the neighboring vertices and incident edges from a vertex in a graph. I assume `NeighborhoodVertices` (from the `GraphUtilities` package) can be used for the former. Anything better?

Or given something like `{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}`, how to directly get these information? Can I do list matching to some pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A random graph

```
 g = RandomGraph[{15, 35}, VertexLabels -> "Name", PlotRangePadding -> .2]
```

[image]

Edges for the vertex 4:

```
 EdgeList[g, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] _]
```

Result:

[image]

Now vertexes around vertex4:

```
 VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, 4]]
```

Result:

```
 {4, 14, 11, 6, 7, 9, 13, 15}
```

Illustration:

```
  HighlightGraph[g, NeighborhoodGraph[g, 4]]
```

[image]

There are many other ways. You could also use `AdjacencyMatrix` to get all that info.

Comment: yes, `NeighborhoodVertices[g, 4, 1]` can also get the same list with shorter typing. :)

Comment: @QiangLi Only if you use `GraphUtilities` package - which I do not. ;-) I use built in `Graph` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1]
g = RandomGraph[{15, 35}, VertexLabels -> "Name",  PlotRangePadding  -> .2];
```

Neighboring edges can also be obtained using `IncidenceList`:

```
IncidenceList[g, 4]
```

> {2 <-> 4, 4 <-> 9, 4 <-> 10, 4 <-> 13, 4 <-> 14}

Neighboring  vertices can be obtained using `VertexList` or `VertexComponent` on the output of `IncidenceList`

```
neighborhoodVerticesAndEdges = {VertexList@#, #} &@IncidenceList[g, 4]
```

> {{2, 4, 9, 10, 13, 14}, {2 <-> 4, 4 <-> 9, 4 <-> 10, 4 <-> 13, 4 <->  14}}

```
{Sort@VertexComponent[#, 4], #} &@IncidenceList[g, 4] == neighborhoodVerticesAndEdges
```

> True

or using `AdjacencyList`:

```
{Union[AdjacencyList@##, {#2}], IncidenceList@##} &[g, 4]  == neighborhoodVerticesAndEdges
```

> True

```
Row[{g, HighlightGraph[g, Join @@ neighborhoodVerticesAndEdges]}]
```

[image]